# How do I show convergence of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive real numbers such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$. Suppose that there exists $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $a_{n+k}\leq a_n, \,\,\,\forall n.$

Question: How do I show that $na_n\rightarrow 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Try an easier problem first: Assume the full sequence $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Are you familiar with Abel's Test?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can approach the problem as  follows. I will define a new sequence $\{b_n\}$ by $b_1=a_1+a_2+...+a_k$, $b_2=a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}+...+a_{2k}$,...,$b_n:=a_{(n-1)k+1}+a_{(n-1)k+2}+...+a_{nk}.$ Then, the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is monotone and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n<\infty.$ Moreover, $(n+1)b_{n+1}\leq (n+1)b_n=nb_n+b_n$. If we now define, $\rho_n=nb_n$, then $\rho_{n+1}\leq \rho_n+b_n$ and also $\{\rho_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence because, for $m>n,$ $0\leq \rho_m\leq \rho_n+\sum\limits_{j=n+1}^m b_j$ and thus $|\rho_m-\rho_n|\leq \sum\limits_{j=n+1}^m b_j\rightarrow 0, as\,\,,\, n,m\rightarrow \infty.$ So $\{\rho_n\}$ has a limit.  Suppose now that $\rho_n$ does not converge to $0$. Then there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that  $\rho_n\geq \epsilon_0$ for all $n.$ Thus $b_n\geq \frac{ \epsilon_0}{n}$ for all $n.$ Thus $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n =\infty.$